# Why doesn't Spring Data MongoDB create a time series collection during direct insertion with @TimeSeries annotation?

Tags: mongodb, time-series, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using Spring Data MongoDB to interact with a MongoDB database. In my application, I have a `Test` class annotated as a time series collection using the `@TimeSeries` annotation as follows:

```
TimeSeries(
    timeField = "timestamp",
    granularity = Granularity.SECONDS,
    metaField = "deviceId")
public class Test {

  @Id private String id;
  private String deviceId;
  private OffsetDateTime timestamp;
  private int measurement;
  .....

  }
```

When I explicitly use the `mongoTemplate.createCollection(Test.class)` method, the collection is created as a time series collection as expected. However, if I directly insert data without pre-creation like:

```
List<Test> testObjectsList = //list of Test objects;
mongoTemplate.insertAll(testObjectsList);
```

It results in a standard collection, despite having the class annotated with `@TimeSeries`.

Why does this happen? Why doesn't MongoDB recognize the `@TimeSeries` annotation during direct insertion?